# Await for API response in a loop

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I am iterating over an array and making a REST API call for each item, but I'm having trouble with the async nature of js. I am trying to use async/await but I don't think I'm setting it up correctly because it won't wait for the response and returns undefined.

```
onSearchSuccess = async (response) => {
  const persons = response._embedded.persons_search_collection;
  const personsWithClasses = await persons.reduce(
  (acc, person) => {
    const params = {
      person_id: person.person_id,
      date: '2017-01-05',
      enrollment_status: 3,
      class_status: 2,
    };
    return getClasses( //this function does an GET request and returns the response
      params,
      (classesResponse) => {
        const { classes } = classesResponse._embedded;
        console.log(classes); //logs after the console.log below
        return [...acc, { ...person, classes }];
      },
      () => acc,
    );
  }, []);
console.log(personsWithClasses); //return undefined
}


export const getClasses = (params, success, error) => {
  axios.get(`${uri}/classes`, { params })
  .then(({ data }) => {
    success(data);
  })
  .catch(err => error(err));
};
```

Comment: If `getClasses` classes returns a promise, then you cannot do `[...acc]` because `acc` will be a promise. Why are you using `reduce` here? What *exactly* are you trying to achieve? Do you want to execute all the REST sequentially? Or simply wait until all requests are done?

Comment: Basically I have an array of people, I am doing a request to get the classes for each person, if there are classes on that day for that person then return an object with both the person and the person's classes, otherwise just return the accumulator and move on. I basically want to filter out the people without classes and return a new object with the person's properties and the classes if they do.

Comment: Would it help if i provide the code for `getClasses`?

Comment: `reduce` is synchronous though. Using an async function (what `getClasses` is) as `reduce` callback doesn't make sense. Use `.map` and `Promise.all` instead.

Comment: ok, thanks i'll rewrite it to use promise.all

Comment: the issue I'm having with promise.all is that if there is a person without classes it will throw the reject and not continue on

Comment: So `getClasses` returns a promise that gets rejected?

Comment: I updated with the code for getClasses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, `reduce` won't work as you want if you call async functions. You can use `Promise.all` and `.map` as so (I tried to use `async/await` as much as possible):

```
onSearchSuccess = async (response) => {
  const persons = response._embedded.persons_search_collection;
  let personsWithClasses = await Promise.all(persons.map(async (person) => {
    try {
      const classes = await getClasses({
        person_id: person.person_id,
        date: '2017-01-05',
        enrollment_status: 3,
        class_status: 2,
      });

      return {...person, classes};
    } catch(error) {
      // ignore errors if a person wasn't found
      return null;
    }
  }));
  personsWithClasses = personsWithClasses.filter(x => x != null);
  console.log(personsWithClasses);
}


export const getClasses = params => {
  return axios.get(`${uri}/classes`, { params });
};
```

Also note the changes I made to `getClasses`. There is no reason to have it accept callbacks if `axios.get` returns a promise anyway.

Comment: thanks! i forgot to update with the promise.all code I was using but I was getting close. Just didn't have the try/catch part.

Comment: I'm really trying to get this model to work, I've tried so many other things but all failed... one problem, with this part `return {...person, classes};` my version of it is not accepting that `classes` is from a variable created in the line above it. Why is that happening? Here's my version:             `let id = response.faceId return { ...imageName, id }` the id in the creation of it is grayed out, it won't let the id in the return statement use it.